# After upgrading py2neo version code is giving errors

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

Currently production in use versions.

NEO4J==3.2.2

python3.8
py2neo==3.1.2

Now upgrading towards newer version

py2neo==4.2.0

I am facing errors.

with py2neo==3.1.2 this code was working fine

```
selector = NodeSelector(graph)
student_node = selector.select("school", studen_key=studen_key).first()
```

After upgrading the version I have updated the code like this

```
selector = NodeMatcher(graph)
student_node = selector.match("school", studen_key=studen_key).first()
```

but it is throwing errors.

```
py2neo.database.ClientError: SyntaxError: Invalid input '{': expected "+" or "-" (line 1, column 39 (offset: 38))
"MATCH (_:student) WHERE _.student_key = {1} RETURN _"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a mismatch between the py2neo version and the Neo4j version here. Upgrading to py2neo version 4.anything will still give you a version that is several years old, built for the Neo4j of that time. Since then, the parameter syntax has changed, so you cannot use a driver that old with a more recent version of Neo4j.

Upgrade to a far more recent version of py2neo instead.

Comment: But I am not upgrading Neo4j version.

Comment: Then the older version of py2neo didn't use properties internally for any of the functionality you were using. Either way, you'll need a more up to date version of py2neo, as I've definitely fixed this in those.

Comment: Do you have any matrix which provide mapping between py2neo and neo4j compatibility versions ?

Comment: The versions of Neo4j are listed in the docs for the driver:
https://py2neo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#requirements